How to resolve missing library issues when using qasan with a 32-bit ARM web service binary in AFL++?
I am trying to use AFL++ to fuzz a 32-bit ARM binary program with the qasan tool. Unfortunately, the binary I am working with is a web service: /usr/sbin/upnpd. To successfully run it, I have to execute it with the following command because upnpd relies on certain libraries in the file system:
QEMU_LD_PREFIX=./squashfs-root/ afl-fuzz -Q -i input -o out3 -m none -- ./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd @@

The results is as follows
jfkk@jfkk:~/Desktop/_R6400-V1.0.1.18_1.0.15.chk.extracted$ QEMU_LD_PREFIX=./squashfs-root/ afl-fuzz -Q -i input -o out3 -m none -- ./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd @@
afl-fuzz++4.30c based on afl by Michal Zalewski and a large online community
[+] AFL++ is maintained by Marc "van Hauser" Heuse, Dominik Maier, Andrea Fioraldi and Heiko "hexcoder" Eißfeldt
[+] AFL++ is open source, get it at https://github.com/AFLplusplus/AFLplusplus
[+] NOTE: AFL++ >= v3 has changed defaults and behaviours - see README.md
[+] No -M/-S set, autoconfiguring for "-S default"
[*] Getting to work...
[+] Using exploration-based constant power schedule (EXPLORE)
[+] Enabled testcache with 50 MB
[+] Generating fuzz data with a length of min=1 max=1048576
[*] Checking core_pattern...
[*] Checking CPU scaling governor...
[+] You have 16 CPU cores and 4 runnable tasks (utilization: 25%).
[+] Try parallel jobs - see /usr/local/share/doc/afl/fuzzing_in_depth.md#c-using-multiple-cores
[*] Setting up output directories...
[+] Output directory exists but deemed OK to reuse.
[*] Deleting old session data...
[+] Output dir cleanup successful.
[*] Checking CPU core loadout...
[+] Found a free CPU core, try binding to #0.
[*] Validating target binary...
[*] Scanning 'input'...
[*] Creating hard links for all input files...
[+] Loaded a total of 1 seeds.
[*] No auto-generated dictionary tokens to reuse.
[*] Attempting dry run with 'id:000000,time:0,execs:0,orig:unsubPublic_UPNP_Event_1'...
[*] Spinning up the fork server...
[+] All right - old fork server is up.
[*] Target map size: 65536
    len = 159, map size = 61, exec speed = 6071 us, hash = 94aebfbb9571be76
[+] All test cases processed.
[+] Here are some useful stats:

    Test case count : 1 favored, 0 variable, 0 ignored, 1 total
       Bitmap range : 61 to 61 bits (average: 61.00 bits)
        Exec timing : 6071 to 6071 us (average: 6071 us)

[*] No -t option specified, so I'll use an exec timeout of 40 ms.
[+] All set and ready to roll!


       AFL ++4.30c {default} (./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd) [explore]       
┌─ process timing ────────────────────────────────────┬─ overall results ────┐
│        run time : 0 days, 0 hrs, 0 min, 1 sec       │  cycles done : 0     │
│   last new find : none seen yet                     │ corpus count : 1     │
│last saved crash : none seen yet                     │saved crashes : 0     │
│ last saved hang : none seen yet                     │  saved hangs : 0     │
├─ cycle progress ─────────────────────┬─ map coverage┴──────────────────────┤
│  now processing : 0.2 (0.0%)         │    map density : 0.09% / 0.09%      │
│  runs timed out : 0 (0.00%)          │ count coverage : 1.00 bits/tuple    │
├─ stage progress ─────────────────────┼─ findings in depth ─────────────────┤
│  now trying : havoc                  │ favored items : 1 (100.00%)         │
│ stage execs : 11/100 (11.00%)        │  new edges on : 1 (100.00%)         │
│ total execs : 135                    │ total crashes : 0 (0 saved)         │
│  exec speed : 78.25/sec (slow!)      │  total tmouts : 10 (0 saved)        │
├─ fuzzing strategy yields ────────────┴─────────────┬─ item geometry ───────┤
│   bit flips : 0/0, 0/0, 0/0                        │    levels : 1         │
│  byte flips : 0/0, 0/0, 0/0                        │   pending : 0         │
│ arithmetics : 0/0, 0/0, 0/0                        │  pend fav : 0         │
│  known ints : 0/0, 0/0, 0/0                        │ own finds : 0         │
│  dictionary : 0/0, 0/0, 0/0, 0/0                   │  imported : 0         │
│havoc/splice : 0/100, 0/0                           │ stability : 100.00%   │
│py/custom/rq : unused, unused, unused, unused       ├───────────────────────┘
│    trim/eff : 97.48%/11, n/a                       │          [cpu000: 31%]
└─ strategy: explore ────────── state: started :-) ──┘^C

+++ Testing aborted by user +++
[*] Writing out3/default/fastresume.bin ...
[+] Written fastresume.bin with 270441 bytes!
[+] We're done here. Have a nice day!


However, when I attempt to use python3 ~/tools/qasan/qasan
AFL_DEBUG=1 QEMU_LD_PREFIX=./squashfs-root/ afl-fuzz -U -i input -o out3 -m none -- python3 ~/tools/qasan/qasan ./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd @@

it fails to locate some required libraries.
jfkk@jfkk:~/Desktop/_R6400-V1.0.1.18_1.0.15.chk.extracted$ AFL_DEBUG=1 QEMU_LD_PREFIX=./squashfs-root/ afl-fuzz -U -i input -o out3 -m none -- python3 ~/tools/qasan/qasan ./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd @@
[+] Enabled environment variable AFL_DEBUG with value 1
[+] Enabled environment variable AFL_DEBUG with value 1
afl-fuzz++4.30c based on afl by Michal Zalewski and a large online community
[+] AFL++ is maintained by Marc "van Hauser" Heuse, Dominik Maier, Andrea Fioraldi and Heiko "hexcoder" Eißfeldt
[+] AFL++ is open source, get it at https://github.com/AFLplusplus/AFLplusplus
[+] NOTE: AFL++ >= v3 has changed defaults and behaviours - see README.md
[+] No -M/-S set, autoconfiguring for "-S default"
[*] Getting to work...
[+] Using exploration-based constant power schedule (EXPLORE)
[+] Enabled testcache with 50 MB
[+] Generating fuzz data with a length of min=1 max=1048576
[*] Checking core_pattern...
[*] Checking CPU scaling governor...
[+] You have 16 CPU cores and 3 runnable tasks (utilization: 19%).
[+] Try parallel jobs - see /usr/local/share/doc/afl/fuzzing_in_depth.md#c-using-multiple-cores
[*] Setting up output directories...
[+] Output directory exists but deemed OK to reuse.
[*] Deleting old session data...
[+] Output dir cleanup successful.
[*] Checking CPU core loadout...
[+] Found a free CPU core, try binding to #0.
[*] Validating target binary...
[*] Scanning 'input'...
[*] Creating hard links for all input files...
[+] Loaded a total of 1 seeds.
[*] No auto-generated dictionary tokens to reuse.
[*] Attempting dry run with 'id:000000,time:0,execs:0,orig:unsubPublic_UPNP_Event_1'...
[*] Spinning up the fork server...
AFL forkserver entrypoint: 0xae80
AFL forkserver entrypoint: 0xae80
./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: can't load library 'ld-linux-armhf.so.3'

[-] Hmm, looks like the target binary terminated before we could complete a
handshake with the injected code. You can try the following:

    - The target binary crashes because necessary runtime conditions it needs
      are not met. Try to:
      1. Run again with AFL_DEBUG=1 set and check the output of the target
         binary for clues.
      2. Run again with AFL_DEBUG=1 and 'ulimit -c unlimited' and analyze the
         generated core dump.

    - Possibly the target requires a huge coverage map and has CTORS.
      Retry with setting AFL_MAP_SIZE=10000000.

Otherwise there is a horrible bug in the fuzzer.
Poke the Awesome Fuzzing Discord for troubleshooting tips.

[-] PROGRAM ABORT : Fork server handshake failed
         Location : afl_fsrv_start(), src/afl-forkserver.c:1687


Even after setting the environment variables, the issue persists,
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib:/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc

and I get the following errors:
jfkk@jfkk:~/Desktop/_R6400-V1.0.1.18_1.0.15.chk.extracted$ AFL_DEBUG=1 QEMU_LD_PREFIX=./squashfs-root/ afl-fuzz -U -i input -o out3 -m none -- python3 ~/tools/qasan/qasan ./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd @@
[+] Enabled environment variable AFL_DEBUG with value 1
[+] Enabled environment variable AFL_DEBUG with value 1
afl-fuzz++4.30c based on afl by Michal Zalewski and a large online community
[+] AFL++ is maintained by Marc "van Hauser" Heuse, Dominik Maier, Andrea Fioraldi and Heiko "hexcoder" Eißfeldt
[+] AFL++ is open source, get it at https://github.com/AFLplusplus/AFLplusplus
[+] NOTE: AFL++ >= v3 has changed defaults and behaviours - see README.md
[+] No -M/-S set, autoconfiguring for "-S default"
[*] Getting to work...
[+] Using exploration-based constant power schedule (EXPLORE)
[+] Enabled testcache with 50 MB
[+] Generating fuzz data with a length of min=1 max=1048576
[*] Checking core_pattern...
[*] Checking CPU scaling governor...
[+] You have 16 CPU cores and 3 runnable tasks (utilization: 19%).
[+] Try parallel jobs - see /usr/local/share/doc/afl/fuzzing_in_depth.md#c-using-multiple-cores
[*] Setting up output directories...
[+] Output directory exists but deemed OK to reuse.
[*] Deleting old session data...
[+] Output dir cleanup successful.
[*] Checking CPU core loadout...
[+] Found a free CPU core, try binding to #0.
[*] Validating target binary...
[*] Scanning 'input'...
[*] Creating hard links for all input files...
[+] Loaded a total of 1 seeds.
[*] No auto-generated dictionary tokens to reuse.
[*] Attempting dry run with 'id:000000,time:0,execs:0,orig:unsubPublic_UPNP_Event_1'...
[*] Spinning up the fork server...
AFL forkserver entrypoint: 0xae80
AFL forkserver entrypoint: 0xae80
./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: '/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6' library contains unsupported TLS
./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: '/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/libc.so.6' library contains unsupported TLS

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_uldivmod': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '_Unwind_GetRegionStart': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_uidiv': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_ldivmod': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '_Unwind_GetLanguageSpecificData': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_cdcmple': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__gnu_unwind_frame': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_cfcmple': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__divdi3': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '_Unwind_GetTextRelBase': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_f2lz': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_d2ulz': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_cfrcmple': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_ul2f': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_ul2d': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '_Unwind_VRS_Set': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '_Unwind_VRS_Get': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_d2lz': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_cdrcmple': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__udivmoddi4': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '_Unwind_VRS_Pop': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_idiv': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_l2f': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_f2ulz': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '__aeabi_l2d': can't resolve symbol

./squashfs-root/usr/sbin/upnpd: symbol '_Unwind_GetDataRelBase': can't resolve symbol

[-] Hmm, looks like the target binary terminated before we could complete a
handshake with the injected code. You can try the following:

    - The target binary crashes because necessary runtime conditions it needs
      are not met. Try to:
      1. Run again with AFL_DEBUG=1 set and check the output of the target
         binary for clues.
      2. Run again with AFL_DEBUG=1 and 'ulimit -c unlimited' and analyze the
         generated core dump.

    - Possibly the target requires a huge coverage map and has CTORS.
      Retry with setting AFL_MAP_SIZE=10000000.

Otherwise there is a horrible bug in the fuzzer.
Poke the Awesome Fuzzing Discord for troubleshooting tips.

[-] PROGRAM ABORT : Fork server handshake failed
         Location : afl_fsrv_start(), src/afl-forkserver.c:1687


Is there any way to resolve this issue? I would really appreciate any guidance or suggestions. Thank you in advance!
